# Passing resource to XamlReader

Tags: xaml, uwp

I am using [XamlReader::Load](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.markup.xamlreader#Windows_UI_Xaml_Markup_XamlReader_Load_System_String_) to parse `DataTemplate`. Is it possible to pass static resources such as value converter? Also, is there a way to modify the resulting `DataTemplate` after loading; for instance, attaching event handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to pass static resources such as value converter?

Yes. You could do it. You just need to note that `Any custom assemblies referenced in a XAML namespace mapping must already be available to the application.`

I've made code sample for your reference, my code is C# code, but the datatemplate string is the same.

```cs
namespace AppXamlLoad
{
    public class MyConverter:IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            return "test";
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
StringBuilder sbTemp = new StringBuilder();
sbTemp.Append("<DataTemplate ");
sbTemp.Append("xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation' ");        
sbTemp.Append("xmlns:x='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml' ");
sbTemp.Append("xmlns:local='using:AppXamlLoad'>");
sbTemp.Append("<Grid>");
sbTemp.Append("<Grid.Resources>");
sbTemp.Append("<local:MyConverter x:Key='myconverter'></local:MyConverter>");
sbTemp.Append("</Grid.Resources>");
sbTemp.Append("<TextBox Margin='2'");
sbTemp.Append(" Text='{Binding");
sbTemp.Append(" Converter={StaticResource myconverter}}'/>");
sbTemp.Append("</Grid>");
sbTemp.Append("</DataTemplate>");
DataTemplate dt = XamlReader.Load(sbTemp.ToString()) as DataTemplate;
mylsiview.ItemTemplate = dt; //mylistview is my listview control in xaml page
```

> is there a way to modify the resulting DataTemplate after loading; for instance, attaching event handler?

Yes.

> Object creation logic cannot integrate the loaded XAML with code-behind classes at run time. If you want to add event handlers, you must do so in code by referencing objects obtained from within the object tree structure of the Load result, and using language-specific syntax for attaching handlers. From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.markup.xamlreader#Remarks)

Jerry Nixon has replied a similar thread, please refer to it for details:[Handle an event in a Data Template loaded by XamlReader.Load(xaml) in code-behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34704890/handle-an-event-in-a-data-template-loaded-by-xamlreader-loadxaml-in-code-behin)